# How to sort several parameter and spot out certain row?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to find out the data with same product ID, company name, but an opposite 'Direction'(i.e. a group of them have to be "BUY" and another group have to be "SELL"). Then I would like to export the data to two sheet; The first one will consist of pairs of data with equal "Amount",in opposite 'Direction'. The second one will consist of group of data that is from same "company" and same "productID", and their total of "Amount" is the same as another group of opposite "direction". And export the data to new sheet with only the column "company","product ID", "Direction" and "amount".

Data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmdue.png)

Sheet1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSvDr.png)

Sheet2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8siBP.png)

I have no idea how can I done the task, seems that I can sort the column"company","product ID" and "Direction" for three times, but it is hard to test the "amount" if I use a basic for loop to run through the rows. Either the result will be repetitive or some of them is missing.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub x()

    ' reference to extensibility library

    Dim objMyProj As VBProject
    Dim objVBComp As VBComponent

    Set objMyProj = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject

    For Each objVBComp In objMyProj.VBComponents
        If objVBComp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
            objVBComp.Export "C:\temp\" & objVBComp.Name & ".bas"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```